How can implement deno organize imports like vscode in neovim with nvim-lsp
How can i implement a command on denols that organize imports like vscode does? I use nvim-lsp
example for typescript:
local function organize_imports()
  local params = {
    command = "_typescript.organizeImports",
    arguments = {vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)},
    title = ""
  }
  vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(params)
end

lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  commands = {
    OrganizeImports = {
      organize_imports,
      description = "Organize Imports"
    }
  }
}

